# How to append to a slice pointer receiver

Tags: go

I have a type alias for a slice. And I want to be able to append to the slice (or filter from the slice) when the slice is a pointer receiver:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type itself []string

func (h itself) appendToItself(test string) {
    h = append(h, test)
}

func main() {
    h := itself{"1", "2"}
    h.appendToItself("3")
    fmt.Println(h, "<- how do I make it [1,2,3]")
}
```

Log:

```
[1 2] <- how do I make it [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to actually pass a pointer, try:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type itself []string

func (h *itself) appendToItself(test string) {
    *h = append(*h, test)
}

func main() {
    h := itself{"1", "2"}
    h.appendToItself("3")
    fmt.Println(h, "<- how do I make it [1,2,3]")
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add on *why* this is needed. The slice itself contains 3 values: a pointer to the underlying array, a "length", and a "capacity". When you pass in a slice, you're passing in a copy of those 3 values. The function can still read and change the items in the slice because it has the right pointer, however, it can not change the length because it's working with a copy of those fields. Using a pointer allows the function to change the "length" of the original.